# OpenVPN specific configuration

Tags: openvpn, dd-wrt, webmin, virtualmin

I have a CentOS 6 w/ virtualmin installation, and recently added the openvnp webmin module. I want to create a VPN server with it, and then connect to it using a dd-wrt openvpn client. The problem is that the options in either platform are difficult to compatibilize.
Has anyone have a clue if i can make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. The first step was to realize why the dd-wrt based router did not started any connection to the server. I could realize that was happening because i could not see ant related packets with tcp-dump in neither of the endpoints. So, the trick was done enabling loggin in the dd-wrt, I could realize that somehow, the openvpn process was waiting for something. That something was the password of the client certificate, so I recreated a certificate without a password. Then, the options were not so difficult to compatibilize. Reading the logs of openvpn in both the server and the router, I was able to set it up.